# AWS IoT - Issue With Device Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, iot, aws-iot

I have a script created using the AWS PHP SDK to bulk upload buttons as things in IoT core whilst simultaneously adding it to the DB on my server.

When using the RegisterThing method and sending a CSR in the parameters argument, the certificate gets created fine and attached to the thing fine and everything with the certificate looks good.

When I go to press the button it's been attached to, I get red flash in the sequence of Long Short Short which, according to AWS is "Cannot establish a secure connection with the server. This error is most likely due to an unknown or inactive certificate.".

If I attach the button to my Lambda function as a trigger, when it doesn't exist as a thing in IoT core, the button works as expected and doesn't give me an error.

I have compared the certificate created when adding as a trigger in Lambda to my certificate created from CSR. There are almost no differences with the exception of the DN config attached to the CSR.

Any help would be appreciated in understanding why my CSR created certificate gives an error.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on AWS IoT but maybe you also need to attach a policy to the certificate?

Comment: @Aris I am sending a policy with the JSON provision template which is the second argument of the RegisterThing method. The policy works perfectly fine as I've tested it with other buttons which have working certificates.